# Django enumfield index out-of-range

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to understand my mistake in defining an enum field in my model, but I honestly cannot track it down. I apologize in advance for asking a dumb question, but I'd appreciate your help.

This is my model:

```
class StageType(enum.Enum):
    Setup = 0
    DVMStart = 1
    Provision = 2
    FWFlash = 3
    BIOSFlash = 4
    PkgLoad = 5

class Stage(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sttype = enum.EnumField(StageType)
    def __unicode__(self):              #  __str__ on Python 3
        return self.name
```

When I run mkmigrations, I get the following error:

> File "/Volumes/RHCHD/rhc/code/seth/console/models.py", line 24, in 
>       class Stage(models.Model):
>     File "/Volumes/RHCHD/rhc/code/seth/console/models.py", line 26, in Stage
>       sttype = enum.EnumField(StageType)
>     File "/Volumes/RHCHD/rhc/seth/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_enumfield/db/fields.py", line 17, in **init**
>       kwargs['default'] = enum.default()
>     File "/Volumes/RHCHD/rhc/seth/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_enumfield/enum.py", line 87, in default
>       return cls.choices()[0][0]
>   IndexError: list index out of range

Can anyone point the error out to me?

Answer (score 0):

Sigh - just finally figured it out. For anyone following after me who sees this, the problem is that the labels defined in the enum must be expressed as all CAPS. I couldn't find this documented anywhere, so hopefully this will be of help to others.